# maxDistance parameter of Query.Near not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB's C# driver and am trying to get Query.Near to work to return homes for sale within 5, 10, 25, or 50 miles of a center point. Here is the query:

```
var near = Query.Near("Coordinates", coordinates.Latitude, coordinates.Longitude, find.GetRadiansAway(), false);
    //var near = Query.WithinCircle("Coordinates", coordinates.Latitude, coordinates.Longitude, find.GetRadiansAway(), false);
    var query = Collection().Find(near);
    query.Limit = 1000;
    var listings = query.ToList();
```

I'm dividing the mile radius by 62.1868289 to get the radians and inputting that into the query, however it's returning the same amount of homes for sale regardless of what radians value I pass in. I also tried both setting the spherical param to true and using Query.WithinCircle, however neither works any better.

I'm using the latest C# driver (1.0.0.4098), is this a bug in the C# driver, a bug in MongoDB, or am I missing something here?

Here are what the queries look like:

5 miles away (near):

```
db.Listing.find({ "Coordinates" : { "$near" : [39.4812172, -76.6438598], "$maxDistance" : 0.072463768115942032 } });
```

10 miles away (near):

```
db.Listing.find({ "Coordinates" : { "$near" : [39.4812172, -76.6438598], "$maxDistance" : 0.14492753623188406 } });
```

5 miles away (spherical near):

```
db.Listing.find({ "Coordinates" : { "$nearSphere" : [39.4812172, -76.6438598], "$maxDistance" : 0.0012629451881788331 } });
```

10 miles away (spherical near):

```
db.Listing.find({ "Coordinates" : { "$nearSphere" : [39.4812172, -76.6438598], "$maxDistance" : 0.0025258903763576662 } });
```

Here is my test case that returns the same # of results whether I pass in 5 miles away or 25 miles away:

```
[Test]
        public void NearTest()
        {
            var isSpherical = true;
            var latitude = 39.4812172;
            var longitude = -76.6438598;
            var milesAway = 5;
            var distance = milesAway / (isSpherical ? 3959.0 : 69.0);

            //search within 5 miles.
            var near = Query.Near("Coordinates", latitude, longitude, distance, isSpherical);
            var collection = ContextWorker.Database.GetCollection<Schemas.Listing.Listing>("Listing");
            var query = collection.Find(near);
            query.Limit = 1000;
            var listings = query.ToList();
            var count1 = listings.Count;
            //Console.WriteLine("query: {0}", query.ToJson());
            Console.WriteLine(count1 + " results returned that are " + milesAway + " miles away");

            //search within 25 miles.
            milesAway = 25;
            distance = milesAway / (isSpherical ? 3959.0 : 69.0);
            near = Query.Near("Coordinates", latitude, longitude, distance, isSpherical);
            query = collection.Find(near);
            query.Limit = 1000;
            listings = query.ToList();
            var count2 = listings.Count;
            //Console.WriteLine("query: {0}", query.ToJson());
            Console.WriteLine(count2 + " results returned that are " + milesAway + " miles away");

            //values should be different.
            Assert.AreNotEqual(count1, count2, "Returned same results for 5 and 25 miles away");
        }

172 results returned that are 5 miles away
172 results returned that are 25 miles away
Test 'Housters.Test.SearchTest.NearTest' failed: 
  Returned same results for 5 and 25 miles away
  Expected: not 172
  But was:  172
    SearchTest.cs(68,0): at Housters.Test.SearchTest.NearTest()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to determine whether a problem is in the C# driver or in the queries themselves is to get the queries working in the mongo shell first. Then you can write the equivalent query using the C# Query builder. As a final check you can see what the equivalent JSON query would be as follows:

var query = Query.Near(...);
var json = query.ToJson();

Can you provide some sample documents that you think should be returned?

Comment: @Robert The tough thing with the mongo shell is when I run queries it only returns up to 100 results. Even the count method only returns up to 100. So when I'm testing passing different distances in, for many of them it just returns 100 so I don't know if it's returning more as I increase the range or not.

Comment: A couple things with the example: 1. Calling the query.ToJson() method gave me this error - "No serializer found for type: MongoDB.Driver.IMongoFields". 2. I can't use query.WithinCircle because it doesn't sort the results by distance to center.

Comment: The variable you called query should probably be called cursor. You want to call ToJson on a query object not on a cursor (in other words, on the query parameter to Find, not the return value of Find).

Comment: @Robert Hey I just changed your test case by switching to latitude first, longitude second - http://www.pastie.org/1916897 - as this is the format my data is in. It says in the mongodb docs - "where the first 2 elements are x,y coordinates (or y,x - just be consistent)" - so Latitude first should be fine, however the test case fails. Is this my issue, that I don't have Longitude first in my data?

Comment: If you want the results sorted by distance one alternative is to use the GeoNear command instead. See: http://www.pastie.org/1916916.

Comment: The documentation states that when using spherical geo searches the order of the parameters is no longer optional, it *must* be longitude first and the latitude.

Comment: I'm using your test case with near, without spherical, and with latitude first, and yet it doesn't return any results - http://www.pastie.org/1916980 - I tried both dividing the miles away by 69.0 and 3959.0, neither returns results.

Comment: @Robert Is it possible that despite what the documentation says, latitude first doesn't work for any geospatial near queries, regardless of the spherical parameter?

Comment: Got it working, thanks for your help! The key was using collection.GeoNear instead of collection.Find and convert the resulting Hits into a new collection of my object. http://www.pastie.org/1917390

Answer (score 5):

A bunch of problems here:

1. Pretty much all the Mongo geospatial queries take the x-coordinate (longitude) first.
2. When you're not using the spherical queries, Mongo just calculates simple Cartesian distances, and the distance you need to pass is in the same units as your coordinates (likely decimal degrees).
3. If you *do* use a spherical query (either near or within), you do need to specify your distance in radians, but to convert from miles to radians, you need to divide by a much bigger number than 62.1868289. You convert from radians to miles by dividing by the Earth's radius (about 3,959 miles).

The conversion you performed above is actually much closer to the conversion from miles to degrees (divide the distance in miles by about 69).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the latitude first in my Listing.Coordinates object so I pass latitude in first to the function. In point #3 you talk about converting from radians to miles, however I need to convert from miles to radians. Do you know the formula to do this? Or the formula for #2, converting from miles to decimal degrees?

Comment: I did include the conversion from miles to radians: you divide your distance in miles by 3959 to (roughly) convert it to radians. Obviously you'll get a very small number, but remember, radians are huge (the entire circumference of the Earth is only a little over 6 radians).

Comment: I tried both the spherical near with radians (dividing the miles by 3959) and the non-spherical near with degrees (dividing the miles by 69) and both behaved exactly the same as what I'm seeing now, where it keeps returning the same area of homes regardless of what radius I input.

Comment: I have modified my question with the queries that it's generating for both near and spherical near.